# adding the same variable to a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I've the below 3 lists and a value (country[i]) and i want to add the same country[i] to all tuples available:

```
name = ["a", "b", "c"]
age = [1, 2, 3]
city = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
country[i]
```

where country[i] equals to "United States", And i used the following code:

```
user_info = [tuple((t,)) for t in zip(name, age, city, country[i])]
```

When executed i got the following result:

```
[(('a', 1, 'aaa', 'U'),), (('b', 2, 'bbb', 'n'),), (('c', 3, 'ccc', 'i'),)]
```

While what i want is:

```
[('a', 1, 'aaa', 'United States'), ('b', 2, 'bbb', 'United States'), ('c', 3, 'ccc', 'United States)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to each of the item "manually":

```
v = (country[i], )
[t + v for t in zip(name, age, city)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> country = ["United States"]
>>> i = 0
>>> name = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> age = [1, 2, 3]
>>> city = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> v = (country[i], )
>>> [t + v for t in zip(name, age, city)]
[('a', 1, 'aaa', 'United States'), ('b', 2, 'bbb', 'United States'), ('c', 3, 'ccc', 'United States')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [my_tuple + ('United States',) for my_tuple in zip(name, age, city)]
```

Maybe you have list of countries, then

```
result = [my_tuple + (country,) for my_tuple in zip(name, age, city) for country in countries]
```

Answer (score 0):

since country[i] is just "United States" you step through the string with the for loop. So you get each single letter. The list of countries need to be same long as the one of cities.

So it should be

```
country[i] = ["United States", "United States", "United States"]
```

or easier

```
country[i] = ["United States"]*3
```

or you dont step through the country if you have just one