# storing data in database (Postgres)

Tags: python, postgresql, tuples

I asked this question about tuples yesterday :
[adding the same variable to a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227945/adding-the-same-variable-to-a-list-of-tuples)

and @alecxe answer it perfectly but the problem now is with ( PostgreSQL), when i tried to store the data in postgres i recieved the below error :

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What i tried is :

```
country = (countries[i], )
user_info = [tuple((t,)) + country for t in zip(name, age, city)]
query = "INSERT INTO users_info (name, age, city, country) VALUES %s"
cur.executemany(query, user_info)
con.commit()
```

Then i recieved the Error, also i tried the below :

```
user_info = [tuple((t,)) + country for t in zip(name, age, city, country)]
```

And recieved the same error again, then i tried something else:

```
user_info = [tuple((t,)) for t in zip(name, age, city, country)]
```

I got it right but with one issue ( last column country ) stored all countries as unique even i didn't specify the column as unique when creating the database:

Database result:

```
name | age |  city | country                  
-----+-----+-------+---------------
a    |  1  |  aaa  | United States
d    |  4  |  ddd  | UK
e    |  5  |  eee  | Canada
```

Creating database:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_info (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, age INT, city VARCHAR(255), country TEXT NOT NULL)")
```

I want all the users to show up even if they are from the same country..

Comment: Have you tried `user_info = [t + country for t in zip(name, age, city)]` which was suggested in your previous question? Print `user_info` in each case, look at it carefully and figure out when it fails and when it works.

Comment: yes already, but it gives me the same TypeError when trying to store the data to postgres.. sorry didn't meniton it in the Question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four fields in your table, so you need four placeholders in the SQL-statement:

```
country = (countries[i], )
user_info = [t + country for t in zip(name, age, city)]
query = "INSERT INTO users_info (name, age, city, country) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
cur.executemany(query, user_info)
con.commit()
```

Comment: it worked just fine, i found a tutorial before mentioned that in query just to write only one ( %s ) not as what you wrote.. What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is, that the tutorial is wrong and does not work and my solution works.